# UPS and server at different Aperages

Tags: ups

I have bought a DELL EMC PowerEdge R740 server which hosts:
2x Intel Xeon SKL-EP Gold 6130,
1x NVIDIA Tesla V100 32GB,
12x 8GB DDR4-2666MHz ECC RAM

It has one main and one backup power supply each @ 2000W and came with a C19-port cable rated at 16 Amperes.

On the other hand, we have a UPS IST3-J 6KW, which can support a C19 output from UPS at max 10 Amperes.

---

QUESTION: Is it safe to power the EMC server from this UPS (10 A)?

Comment: This site is about design of electronic circuits and not about whether a purchased electrical item is going to be compatible with another unless you can provide full tech specs and/or schematics.

Comment: OK, thnx. Where should I post it? Any idea?

Comment: The UPS is underrated for the application. Get a UPS that is good for at least 20 Amps so that it will pick up the full load in the event of a power outage. This question is a logical duplicate that has been asked numerous times.

Answer (score 0):

Power (W) = current (A) × voltage (V).

We don't know what's your voltage, but even assuming 240 V that UPS can deliver up to 240 V × 10 A = 2400 W of power. Take into account that your power supplies are rated for 2000 W of *provided* power, but their efficiency is less than 100%, so they will draw *more* than 2000 W under full load. That means that the UPS can just barely power a single PSU under full load.

If your voltage is for example 115 V, UPS's power delivery capabilities would be 115 V %times; 10 A = 1150 W. That's half of what a single power supply can draw.

Answer (score 0):

On these dual-PSU systems it is designed such that 1 PSU can feed the server so with both connected you only will use half of the total power on each PSU.
I'm assuming you want to hookup 1 PSU to the UPS and the other directly to mains power. That is the normal way of doing this.

So worst case (if mains power fails) you will draw the maximum load (2000W) on the PSU connected to the UPS.
P = V * I
At 2000 W and 240 V, I will be 2000/240 = 8.3 Ampere
So that is well within the output of the UPS.

If you are on 120 V things will be problematic: 2000/120 = 16.7 A
That is too much for your UPS. You won't fry it (if it is properly designed), but you might trip an internal  circuit breaker on the UPS if you try this.

Having said that: It is quite possible your server doesn't actually use the full 2000W. That depends highly on the CPU TDP, the load on CPU and GPU, amount of RAM, amount of network traffic, PCIe card(s), number of disks and the disk-load. Too many variables to make any assumptions about this.

The only way for sure it to measure your real load.
If you UPS has a monitoring/logging function use that with 1 PSU connected to the UPS and the other to mains power.
Put the server under load (for some time, you want it running hot and the fans going at max speed) and measure the Amps on the UPS.
If that doesn't exceed 45% of UPS capacity you can assume that the UPS can carry the load, because worst case it will see twice that load.
(Don't calculate with 50%. That gives no margin for fluctuations in power-usage. One should never operate an UPS at 100% output load!)